# Importing Material-ui components at once

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it a good practice to import all of the Material-UI components at once and then use whichever I need? or it has a negative effect on the app performance? I realized that I have to write a lot of `import some-component from '@material-ui/core/...'`.

I mean writing the following code:

```js
import * as Material from "@material-ui/core";
.
.
return (

  <div>
    <Material.Button>Submit</Material.Button>
  </div>

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
import {Button, Dialog} from "@material-ui/core";
.
.
return (

  <div>
    <Button>Submit</Button>
    <Dialog></Dialog>
  </div>

)
```